# making executable icon on linux for .jar file

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am currently exporting my project desktop application as a runnable `JAR` File specification in Eclipse. This creates a jar file which can be executed in windows by double clicking it, but how do you make it an .exe with an icon like regular windows applications?

In Linux it does not run by double clicking so I had to create an executable file with this command:

```
java -jar sampleApp.jar
```

so I am having to run a separate script to start the application, how can I make it an executable program in linux with an icon ?

Comment: Is this a desktop app. (e.g. Swing, Java-FX, SWT..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> ..JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, ***desktop integration,*** file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Note that 'desktop integration' means - an icon on the desktop (as well as potentially a menu item - like on the Windows Start Menu).